# springfox + swagger not working

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

my pom.xml

```
<!-- Swagger io for API doc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Swagger config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                 .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
                  .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("allocation-order-service")
                .description("domain services having persistance layer")
                .version("1.0")
                .build();
    }
}
```

server logs

```
16-05-18 13:08:59.137       ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]  INFO    o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  registerHandlerMethod        190    Mapped "{[/${springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path:/v2/api-docs}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json || application/hal+json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
16-05-18 13:08:59.141       ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]  INFO    o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  registerHandlerMethod        190    Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/security],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.securityConfiguration()
16-05-18 13:08:59.143       ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]  INFO    o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  registerHandlerMethod        190    Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/ui],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.uiConfiguration()
16-05-18 13:08:59.145       ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]  INFO    o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  registerHandlerMethod        190    Mapped "{[/swagger-resources],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource>> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.swaggerResources()
```

it says Mapped : `/${springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path:/v2/api-docs}`

but none of these work (404):

```
http://localhost:8080/allocation-order-web/v2/api-docs
http://localhost:8080/allocation-order-web/${springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path:/v2/api-docs}
```

If I use spring-fox lower version then I will get in my logs that it has Mapped "{[/v2/api-docs}],methods=[GET]. However, I'm not able to see any json generated there.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to specify your main application context path along with the *swagger* documentation path (you should better define them in a custom properties file or under *application.properties*):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger2
@PropertySource("classpath:swagger-v2.properties")
public class SwaggerConfig {
    //...
}
```

The *swagger-v2.properties* should look as follows:

```
server.contextPath=/allocation-order-web/
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/api-docs
```

Documentation should been then accessible through:

***http://localhost:8080/allocation-order-web/api-docs***

Answer (score 0):

Well just this willl not work

```
http://localhost:8080/allocation-order-web/v2/api-docs
```

you need to pass group attr as well try this

```
http://localhost:8080/allocation-order-web/v2/api-docs?group=public-api
```

Comment: it's still giving 404

Comment: that's weird ..  for me without any group attr it shows 404 but once I added group=public-api it worked.

Comment: I added a VM arg springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/swagger , then tried http://localhost:8080/allocation-order-web/swagger?group=public-api. Still getting 404